# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind' Tkitner

Tags: python, tkinter, types

I am trying to bind a function to my EntryBox.

```
nameEntry = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=nameInput,bg="white",font=("Arial",28)).grid(row=2,column=2)
nameEntry.bind("<FocusOut>",nameValidation(nameInput.get()))
```

However I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

The result of `type(nameEntry)`

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

When I remove the .bind line, the tkinter GUI loads perfectly. I am confused as to why `nameEntry` is being treated as 'NoneType'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `grid()` methods returns `None`... that's the whole issue. So, split the first line into two line so:

```
nameEntry = tk.Entry(root,textvariable=nameInput,bg="white",font=("Arial",28))
nameEntry.grid(row=2,column=2)
```